# Plotting roots found using Reduce

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, graphics

I want to create a 2D scatter plot using roots found by the `Reduce` function; i.e., all integer points on a circle.

[image]

`Reduce[x^2 + y^2 == 5^2, {x, y}, Integers]`

How do I achieve this?

Comment: In this very special case, try `ListPlot[Reduce[x^2 + y^2 == 5^2, {x, y}, Integers] /. {And | Or -> List, _ == a_ :> a}]`. But this is fragile and only works because the output is structured so nicely.

Comment: `ListPlot[SolveValues[x^2 + y^2 == 5^2, {x, y}, Integers], AspectRatio -> 1]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sol = Reduce[x^2 + y^2 == 5^2, {x, y}, Integers];
reg = ImplicitRegion[sol, {x, y}];
Region[reg, BaseStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Red}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I like it because this is a natural way.

Answer (score 4):

```
pts = {x, y} /. {ToRules[Reduce[x^2 + y^2 == 5^2, {x, y}, Integers]]}
circ = CircleThrough[RandomChoice[pts, 3]]

ListPlot[pts
 , PlotStyle -> Directive[Black
   , AbsolutePointSize[6]]
 , AspectRatio -> Automatic
 , Epilog -> {
   Dashed, Red, circ
   }
 ]
```

[image]

---

A labeled variant:

```
ListPlot[Callout[#, #] & /@ pts
 , PlotStyle -> Directive[Black
   , AbsolutePointSize[6]]
 , AspectRatio -> Automatic
 , Frame -> True
 , Epilog -> {
   Dashed, Red, circ
   }
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Inelegant, but revealing:

```
jj = Reduce[x^2 + y^2 == 25, {x, y}, Integers];

kk = Table[{jj[[i, 1, 2]], jj[[i, 2, 2]]}, {i, Length[jj]}];

Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point /@ kk}, GridLines -> {Range[-5, 5], Range[-5, 5]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am sure there are 10 ways to do this. One another way could be

```
sol = Reduce[x^2 + y^2 == 5^2, {x, y}, Integers];
List @@ Map[{First[#][[2]], Last[#][[2]]} &, sol];
Graphics[{
  {Opacity[.1], Blue, Disk[]},
  {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[points]},
  {Text[ToString[#], #, {-1.5, 0}] & /@ points}
  },
 Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you do not want the disk, you can remove it.